# Google Sheets embed into website with formatted table

Tags: google-sheets

I usually record students marks in a Google Sheet. However Google's embed provides a "mirror" of the Sheets and looks exactly like the sheet. This means I have to resize the cells so as to show the complete names and perform formatting. Is there a better way of displaying this information without resizing the cells. I need a method which automatically displays a the data without any configuration. If possible without the use of Google Apps Script.Here is the sample data. The data will be sent to parents and will also be printed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nKcShloX5R4OvhuEtRogCHG18V1YTR5v9Hb19Jobm88/pubhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Visualizations API. This automatically resizes the cells and produces a neat and minimal looking table.

This is the usage:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheet-id>/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=2
```

So in your case:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nKcShloX5R4OvhuEtRogCHG18V1YTR5v9Hb19Jobm88/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=2

The difference is very clear.

Comment: exactly what I wanted.